# Javascript how to add addEventListener after bootstrap modal shows

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal

How to add "addEventListener" after bootstrap modal shows with pure javascript not jQuery. The point of this is to get one of the modals div width when it loads. Version of bootstrap 4.6!!!!

Comment: The best solution would be to read the Bootstrap documentation since it shows how to do this with plain JavaScript.  See: [Bootstrap Modal Events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#events)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shown.bs.modal` event listener for example you need to select the modal, let's say the modal `id` equal to `myModal`

```
const modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
modal.addEventListner('shown.bs.modal', () => {
  // enter your code here.
})
```

[RESOURCE](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#how-it-works)

Comment: this isn't work with pure JS

Comment: Are you sure that you `script` is after the `bootstrap script`

Comment: Yes i use Yii2 and I loaded sript at the end and still nothing :/